# R: Comparison between columns in two data frames to add value from specific column if all conditions matched

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have two data frames named `bld_g` and `cat_df`.

```
# Creating bld_g
bld_g <- tibble(
  st_con_rt = c("sub-room", "", "main-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "", "main-room", "main-room", "main-room", "main-room", "", "sub-room"),
  st_con_tr = c("direct", "", "direct", "direct", "direct", "direct", "direct", "", "terrace", "terrace", "direct", "terrace", "", "terrace"),
  st_th = c("", "", "hira", "", "", "", "", "", "tsuma", "tsuma", "tsuma", "tsuma", "", ""),
  st_adsb = c("add", "", "sub", "sub", "add", "add", "add", "", "add", "add", "sub", "add", "", "sub"),
  tr_adsb = c("sub", "", "", "sub", "sub", "", "sub", "", "sub", "sub", "add", "sub", "", "sub"),
  st_sub_main_th = c("tsuma", "hira", "hira", "hira", "hira", "hira", "NA", "other", "", "", "", "", "hira", "hira"),
  roo_com = c("3b+7", "2a+7", "1b+7", "1a+7", "2a+7", "1a+7", "7", "1b", "1a+7", "4a", "2a", "4a", "7", "2a+7")
)

# Creating cat_df
cat_df <- tibble(
  type = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
  st_con_rt = c("sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "main-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room"),
  st_con_tr = c("direct", "direct", "direct", "direct", "direct", "terrace", "terrace", "terrace", "terrace"),
  st_th = c("tsuma", "tsuma", "tsuma", NA, NA, "tsuma", "tsuma", "tsuma", "tsuma"),
  st_adsb = c("add", "add", "add", "sub", "sub", "add", "add", "add", "add"),
  tr_adsb = c("sub", "sub", "sub", "sub", "sub", "sub", "sub", "sub", "sub"),
  st_sub_main_th = c("hira", "hira", "hira", "hira", "hira", NA, "hira", "hira", "hira"),
  roo_com = c("1a+7", "2a+7", "4a", "1a+7", "2a+7", "4a", "1a+7", "2a+7", "4a")
)
```

`cat_df` is a reference data and `bld_g` is the one that I need to update. They share the same fields but different values. `cat_df` contains `type` field which I want to insert into `bld_g`.

What I need to do is:

- Find a corresponding row from `cat_df` for each row of `bld_g` by comparing all values in each field (excluding `type` in `cat_df`) whether all field values match or not
- If all values in `bld_g` are the same with `cat_df`, copy `type` value from `cat_df` to `bld_g` (additional column name will be `type`), else put 0
- If there is a `NA` in `cat_df`, that column can be omitted from comparison

Some fields in `bld_g` contain empty. It just means `no information`. It does not have any special meaning.

In this way I want to determine which type each row of `bld_g` belong to.

I found several posts which are similar to my issue such as [Compare columns between two data frames R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951130/compare-columns-between-two-data-frames-r) but it is not suitable for my case.

I thought it could be easily solved by multiple `left_join` like this, but it does not work as `bld_g` contains empty.

```
outcome <- bld_g %>% left_join(cat_df, by=c("st_con_rt", "st_con_tr",
  "st_th", "st_adsb", "tr_adsb", "st_sub_main_th", "roo_com"))
```

I usually use `dplyr` family for data manipulation but other solutions are welcomed as well. Hope your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is the thing you are after

```
bld_g %>%
  mutate(cat = {
    match(
      do.call(paste, .),
      cat_df %>%
        mutate(across(-type, ~ if_else(is.na(.x), "", .x))) %>%
        {
          do.call(paste, select(., -type))
        }
    )
  })
```

which gives the `cat` column identifying the row number in `cat_df`

```
# A tibble: 14 × 8
   st_con_rt   st_con_tr st_th   st_adsb tr_adsb st_sub_main_th roo_com   cat
   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>          <chr>   <int>
 1 "sub-room"  "direct"  ""      "add"   "sub"   "tsuma"        3b+7       NA
 2 ""          ""        ""      ""      ""      "hira"         2a+7       NA
 3 "main-room" "direct"  "hira"  "sub"   ""      "hira"         1b+7       NA
 4 "sub-room"  "direct"  ""      "sub"   "sub"   "hira"         1a+7        4
 5 "sub-room"  "direct"  ""      "add"   "sub"   "hira"         2a+7       NA
 6 "sub-room"  "direct"  ""      "add"   ""      "hira"         1a+7       NA
 7 "sub-room"  "direct"  ""      "add"   "sub"   "NA"           7          NA
 8 ""          ""        ""      ""      ""      "other"        1b         NA
 9 "main-room" "terrace" "tsuma" "add"   "sub"   ""             1a+7       NA
10 "main-room" "terrace" "tsuma" "add"   "sub"   ""             4a          6
11 "main-room" "direct"  "tsuma" "sub"   "add"   ""             2a         NA
12 "main-room" "terrace" "tsuma" "add"   "sub"   ""             4a          6
13 ""          ""        ""      ""      ""      "hira"         7          NA
14 "sub-room"  "terrace" ""      "sub"   "sub"   "hira"         2a+7       NA
```

Comment: Great simple and efficient script. I did not realize that explicit comparison is not necesary. Thank you for the solution!